# ValueError with INI Config File

Tags: python, api, ini, valueerror

**Background -**
I have a python program that calls an API, saves the data to a DataFrame, and writes it to a `.JSON` + `.CSV` file.
As part of this program, I have been exploring using an `.INI` (config) file, which I would like to -

1. Read my API key and secret in my `def api_call():`
2. Read 2x date values (yyyy-mm-dd) required in my `def api_parameters():` function, which are parameters to form a url string, which will be used to make the API call.

**.INI Structure -** (with dummy values!)

```
[firm_api]
key = 6GFDGFSDGSDFGSDFGFSDGFSDGFD
secret = GFSD898F908GFSD09PJGF-80F
[url_params]
start_date = 2021-10-30
end_date = 2021-11-30
```

**Issue -**
I have created a `def config`, which reads my `.INI` file, and attempts to return my API `key` and `secret`, as well as the url parameters of `start_date` and `end_date`.
The problem is that when I call the `def config` from either `def api_parameters` (this is where I need `start_date` and `end_date`) OR `def api_call` (where I need `key` & `secret`) I get the a `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)` error.

**Function that reads the .INI** - this reads my `.INI` file and returns the 4x values mentioned above:

```
def ini_config():
    file = 'authen_config.ini'
    config = ConfigParser()
    config.read(file)
    key = config.get('firm_api', 'key')
    secret = config.get('firm_api', 'secret')
    start_date = config.get('url_params', 'start_date')
    end_date = config.get('url_params', 'end_date')
    return key, secret, start_date, end_date
```

**Function that needs `start_date` and `end_date`-** this function constructs the url to call:

```
def api_parameters():
    start_date, end_date = ini_config()
    str = "https://firm.vendor.com/api/v1/portfolio/views/45265/results?portfolio_id=10&portfolio_type=firm&output_type=json&start_date={}&end_date={}&vendor_firm=333"
    url = str.format(start_date, end_date)
    print("-----------------------\n", "API URLs constructed\n-----------------------")
    return url
api_parameters()
```

**Function that needs `key` and `secret`**- makes the API call:

```
def api_call():
    key, secret = ini_config()
    url = api_parameters()
    response = requests.get(url, auth = HTTPBasicAuth(key, secret), headers={"Vendor-Firm":"333"})
    api_response = json.loads(response.text)
    return api_response
api_call()
```

I think the problem is that although in the `def api_call():` and `def url_parameters():` I am only trying to call `def ini_config():` for the values I need, it is returning all 4x values and confusing the functions.

Does anyone have any suggestions how I can resolve these `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ini_config()` returns 4 values

```
return key, secret, start_date, end_date
```

but you try to assign to 2 variables

```
start_date, end_date = ini_config()
# or 
key, secret = ini_config()
```

and this makes problem.

You have to use 4 variables

```
key, secret, start_date, end_date = ini_config()
```

Or you can use popular `_` as variable to skip some values

```
_, _, start_date, end_date = ini_config()
# or 
key, secret, _, _ = ini_config()
```

---

Eventually you should create two functions - one only to get `keys`, and one to get only `dates`.